# Warrant extension - would this have any tax implications?

Tags: united-states, taxes, options, equity, warrants

If someone has warrants to purchase shares in a private C corp in the US, if they were about to expire and they got the company to agree to extend them, does this have any tax implications?  These are not employee stock options.